# Lectura de tabla sin resultados pero actúa como si los tuviera

Tags: php, mysql

Leo una tabla de emails con una sentencia PDO, si no obtengo resultados envío un mensaje "Propietario sin email"; en caso contrario, muestro el formulario para completar. El problema es que me muestra el formulario ante propietarios que no tienen email:

Código:

```
<?php   

# --- LEE TABLA EMAILS ----------------------------------------------------
$id = $prop['iduser'];
$email = obtener_emails($conexion, $id); 

?>


<?php if (!$email) : ?>

  <!-- Sin Email -->
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Este propietario no cuenta con email</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php else : ?>

<!-- Formulario de Consulta -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Enviar Consulta</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>

      <input type="hidden" name="id_propiedad" id="id_propiedad" value="<?php echo $prop['id']; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="nom_propiedad" id="nom_propiedad" value="<?php echo $prop['nombre']; ?>" />                          
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="control-group form-group">
              <div class="controls">
                  <label>Nombre completo:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Ingrese su nombre.">
                  <p class="help-block"></p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="control-group form-group">
              <div class="controls">
                  <label>Telefono:</label>
                  <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Ingrese su telefono.">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="control-group form-group">
              <div class="controls">
                  <label>Email:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Ingrese su correo electrónico.">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="control-group form-group">
              <div class="controls">
                  <label>Fecha de entrada:</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="desde" required data-validation-required-message="Ingrese fecha de llegada.">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="control-group form-group">
              <div class="controls">
                  <label>Fecha de salida:</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="hasta" required data-validation-required-message="Ingrese fecha de salida.">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="control-group form-group">
              <div class="controls">
                  <label>Cuantas personas:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="personas" placeholder="2 3 4... (solo numeros)" required data-validation-required-message="Ingrese cantidad de ocupantes.">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="control-group form-group">
              <div class="controls">
                  <label>Mensaje:</label>
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Ingrese su mensaje" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div id="success"></div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Mensaje</button>
      </div>
  </form>
  <!-- Fin Formulario de Consulta -->

</div>
```

Código de la lectura:

```
# ------------- Lee tabla EMAILS por id -----------------------------------------------------------
function obtener_emails($conexion, $id){
  $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE estado = 1 AND iduser = $id");
  $sentencia->execute();
  return ($sentencia) ? $sentencia : false;
}
```

Comment: `$sentencia->execute();` te devuelve algo, independiente de si es un registro o un `null`. Por lo que `$email` existe, y te muestra el formulario. [Documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Gracias... pero entonces... como debo hacer la consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiero señalar algunas cosas sobre tu código.

1. No uses `SELECT *` en una consulta que sólo sirve para verificar si hay datos. Es como si te llevaras de viaje 5 ò 10 maletas para luego usar un pantalón y una camisa. :)

   PD: Si necesitas los datos, ok, usa `SELECT columnas que necesitas`.
2. Guardaremos los datos en un array asociativo llamado `$arrDatos` y devolveremos ese valor. Para verificar si hay datos, sólo tienes que evaluar los mismos datos, es decir, si en el destino haces esto: `if ($arrDatos) {...}` entrará en el if solamente si la consulta devolvió datos.
3. Luego puedes leer `$arrDatos` dentro de un bucle para imprimir los resultados.
4. Aplica consultas preparadas para dar seguridad a tu código.

Si optimizamos el código quedaría así. Hay comentarios aclaratorios en el código.

```
function obtener_emails($conexion, $id)
{

/*Verificamos la variable conexión*/
if ($conexion)
{
    /*
     *Escribimos una consulta con marcadores de nombre
     *para aplicar consultas preparadas
    */

     $sql="SELECT * FROM emails WHERE estado = 1 AND iduser = :iduser"

    /*
     *Preparamos la consulta
     *y le pasamos los valores aparte para evitar inyección SQL
     *los valores se pueden pasar directamente mediante el método execute
     *para ello construimos un array con cada parámetro y su valor respectivo
    */

     $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($sql);

    /*Evaluamos también la sentencia SQL*/

    if ($sentencia)
    {

         $arrParams=array(":iduser"=>$id);
         $sentencia->execute($arrParams);

        /*
         *MUY IMPORTANTE: En la variable $arrDatos
         *tendremos los datos en sí existen datos y FALSE si no existen
         *ya que al usar $sentencia con fetchAll este método
         *devuelve un array asociativo con los datos o FALSE según haya datos o no
         *eso es todo lo que hay que verificar
        */

         $arrDatos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     }else{

        echo "Hubo un error en la consulta SQL";
        $arrDatos=array();       
     }

}else{

    echo "La conexión es nula";
    $arrDatos=array();       

}

     return $arrDatos;
}
```

En el destino, donde llamas la función, trabajas con la variable `$arrDatos` devuelta.

Ejemplo de llamada:

```
$id = $prop['iduser']; 

/*
  *Verifiquemos $id
  *Aquí se puede verificar también $conexion
  *En ese caso quitamos la verificación de $conexion en la función
*/

print_r($id);
if ($id){

     $arrDatos = obtener_emails($conexion, $id); 

     if ($arrDatos)
    {
         echo "Hay datos, los leemos";
    }else{
        echo "NO hay datos";
    }

}else{

    echo "Id es nulo";

}
```

Comment: Es muy util y lo agradezco... pero no es solo para ver si hay datos, en el caso que los haya, los necesito para enviar el contenido del formulario a los mais que me surjan de la búsqueda, y en el caso contrario, simplemente desplegar la leyenda que asi lo indique, sin mostrar el formulario.

Comment: @RicardoPastuszek he editado la respuesta con un código que almacena en un array los datos encontrados. Luego sólo tienes que verificar si ese array está vacío o no, si no lo está, entonces obtienes los e-mails.

Comment: Agradezco la intervención, he copiado todo y comprendido, pero sigue habiendo un error y no lo encuentro, ahora... es como que nadie tiene un email, y si que los hay. he utilizado un foreach luego de la llamada de la funcion, para verificar resultados y no muestra nada.
¿No sera la 1er. linea de mi codigo esta colisionando con el tuyo?, me refiero a: $id = $prop['iduser'];

Comment: @RicardoPastuszek haz `echo $id;` para verificar que realmente tu variable tiene datos. Por rapidez olvidé establecer más controles al código que consulta a la BD, para verificar si: -La conexión no es nula; -Si la consulta falla; etc. ¿Si ejecutas la consulta con esos criterior directamente en la BD te devuelve datos? Para más claridad, edita la pregunta, poniendo el código como lo tienes ahora.

Comment: si, ya los habia hecho, y efectivamente hay $id, como asi tambien un email que le corresponde en la otra tabla, pero hago echo del array leido y no muestra nada... no esta almacenando los emails en el array

Comment: ¿Pero te evalúa `if ($arrDatos) ...` con datos o sin datos? Para mostrar el array tienes que usar `print_r($arrDatos);` o `var_dump($arrDatos);`, ya que `echo` no es capaz de mostrar lo que hay en un array.

Comment: si, dije echo por decir que se imprime, probe con print_r y me tira Array() vacio....

Comment: Acabo de ver el fallo @RicardoPastuszek, **¡faltaba el `execute`!**. Revisa el código editado, la parte de la ejecución queda así: `$sentencia = $conexion->prepare($sql);
         $arrParams=array(":iduser"=>$id);
         $sentencia->execute($arrParams);` Podemos enviar los parámetros al `execute` sin necesidad de `bindValue` como estaba antes... no me había percatado de eso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66203/discussion-between-ricardo-pastuszek-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 0):

`$sentencia->execute();` te devuelve algo, independiente de si es un registro o un `null`. Por lo que `$email` existe, y te muestra el formulario.

Tendrás que comprobar si la respuesta es buena. En caso de servirte, manda un `return true`.

```
if (!$sentencia) {
    $mensaje  = 'Consulta no válida: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $mensaje .= 'Consulta completa: ' . $sentencia;
    die($mensaje);
}
```

Puedes recoger los valores de la consulta del siguiente modo:

```
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($sentencia)) {
    echo $fila['nombre'];
    echo $fila['apellido'];
    echo $fila['direccion'];
    echo $fila['edad'];
    //No conozco los campos de tu base de datos pero se entiende
}
```

Te dejo el enlace a la documentación: [Documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)